# How to remove Desktop tab in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde-plasma

I would like to remove the Desktop tab from KDE Plasma desktop environment and get rid of the context menu.  Is there a way to do this ?

[image]

Hi Chris,  Thanks for the reply.   I am running KDE 4.14.8.  I am not seeing what you are describing.   The context menu is  the menu when you right click on the desktop.   I think you are calling it "desktop menu".    My original snapshot show that menu.   That menu changed depending what desktop theme I selected.   I could not find anything call Configure Desktop.   The closest thing to that would be Default Desktop Setting and there is not there about the Tweaks tab.   The project that I am working on is  kind of mission critical.  It would be just a plain desktop without anything.   The only thing the user can do is log on, does his job and log off.   All the things that can distract the user will be removed.   I got most of them except for this pesky toolbox.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with context-menu? The right-click desktop menu?

Comment: If you (for whatever reason) are still on KDE4, please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/24867/how-do-i-remove-the-kde-4-plasma-tool-box-cashew-icon-from-the-desktop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove the toolbox:

- right-click on desktop to get the desktop menu
- select `Configure Desktop`, a dialog appears
- switch to `Tweaks` tab
- uncheck `Show the desktop toolbox`

You can also drag it to a corner (when widgets are unlocked), then it will not show the current activity name, but will still be accessible.